# Can anyone detect error in the following code in python

Tags: python, calculator

Q- design a calculator which will correctly solve all the problems except the folowing one :-
45*3=555, 56+9 = 77, 56/6 = 4

enter code here

```
a = ("enter first number:")
b = ("enter second number:")
print(int(input(a)))
print(int(input(b)))
c = "enter your operator"
print(input(c))
if a==56 and b==9 and c == "+":
    print("77")
elif a==45 and b==3 and c=="*":
    print("555")
elif a==56 and b==6 and c=="/":
    print("4")
else:
    print("error! check your input")
```

Comment: `a = int(input("enter first number:"))` , do it for `b` and `c`

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing:

```
a = ("enter first number:")
b = ("enter second number:")
print(int(input(a)))
print(int(input(b)))
c = "enter your operator"
print(input(c))
```

With:

```
a = int(input("enter first number:"))
b = int(input("enter second number:"))
c = input("enter your operator")
```

Printing integer inputs won't store them to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ("enter first number:") 
b = ("enter second number:") 
print(int(input(a)))  
print(int(input(b)))  
c = "enter your operator" 
print(input(c))
```

Instead of this, apply following change:-

```
a = input("enter first number:")
b = input("enter second number:")
print(int(a))
print(int(a))
c = input("Enter the operator here: ")
print(c)
```

Hope your problem gets resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the values to variables

From above the, 'a' has value "enter first number:" and it doesn't contain '56'

So, you should get input as `a = int(input("enter first number:"))` same for b as well and for c you should use 'str' type.